# Smooth JQuery Show/Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

I'm looking forward to implement a smooth transition when the buttons are clicked, by default when I click them, it shows a little bit "laggy" and I want to make that "smoother"

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    var revealButtons = {
        '.rv_button_1': '.rv_element_1',
        '.rv_button_2': '.rv_element_2',
        '.rv_button_3': '.rv_element_3',
        '.rv_button_4': '.rv_element_4',
        '.rv_button_5': '.rv_element_5',
        '.rv_button_6': '.rv_element_6',
        '.rv_button_7': '.rv_element_7',
        '.rv_button_8': '.rv_element_8',
        '.rv_button_9': '.rv_element_9',
        '.rv_button_10': '.rv_element_10',
        '.rv_button_11': '.rv_element_11',
        '.rv_button_12': '.rv_element_12',
        '.rv_button_13': '.rv_element_13',
        '.rv_button_14': '.rv_element_14',
    };
    $.each(revealButtons, function(revealButton, revealElement) {
        $(revealButton).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(revealElement).slideToggle();
            $(revealButton).toggleClass('rv_button_opened rv_button_closed');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can we get the css on the class -rv_button_opened rv_button_closed

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal There are no styles for those buttons, they are made with DIVI.

Comment: you can use CSS transition to make the click smooth